# Converting hexadecimal string in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I would like to convert a hexadecimal string like 0x444(hexadecimal) to a varchar2 in oracle. This can be done easily for MS-SQL (SELECT CAST(0x4444 AS VARCHAR(10)) ), do we have similar solution in oracle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(hextoraw('4444'))
FROM dual
```